# drupal theme multiupload image field

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-forms, multi-upload

I have one drupal content type. there is one image field, the configuration is:

[content type field setting](http://www.imaboy.cn/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/q1vKz-1024x82.jpg)

It works fine. I can upload multi image to that content type. The only problem is that, the uploaded image is themed in table format.

[uploaded results](http://www.imaboy.cn/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/QQ%E5%9B%BE%E7%89%8720140701180927-500x145.jpg)

How can i change the output format other than table? I have searched for the whole day, still can not find the answer :(

Answer (score 0):

What I have seen from your given images, you have an image field in your content type. Also I am not sure that in which way you are showing all the images on the front end. This could be done in several ways. One of them is using **'Views'**.

**Views**

- So if you are collecting all the images into a view creating a page or block, then you can easily change the showing format. Like you can use the table format and also list format. And on the front end you could be able have a non-tabular format.

**Tpl files**

- On the other hand, if you are using special node tpl then you have to format the html properly so that they won't come in a tabular format.

I will personally suggest you to use the views to avoid unnecessary problems and also you can also specify the view specific tpl file.

**Cheers :) keep Drupalizing :)**

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It is neither views nor tpl. when you upload multi images, the preview is automatically generated. I would like to know which module did that? i have checked image module and multiupload_imagefield_widget module, but can not find where to change.

Comment: Ok, you want to change the preview format! For that some specific module would be responsible which needs to be modified. That's great reorganization. Will update later.